# How to pass value of a widget to a different widget using an accordion in Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget

I'm a beginner in Jupyter. I'm trying to figure out how to 'pass' the value of one widget to became the input of another.

I have a really simple Jupyter accordion, with 2 tabs.

1. The first one ('File type') asks for the desired input file type (in this case, this can be  *.las, *.csv, and *.txt).
2. A list is displayed on the second tab ('Select input files'), containing the files in the working directory matching the required extension.

   ```
   from ipywidgets import IntSlider, Text, Dropdown, Accordion
   from os import listdir
   from os.path import isfile

   global MY_FILE_TYPE

   def read_las():
       pass

   def read_csv():
       pass

   FILE_TYPES_DCT = {'.las': read_las,
                     '.csv': read_csv,
                     '.txt': read_csv}
   file_type_wg = Dropdown(options=FILE_TYPES_DCT.keys(), description='File type:')

   MY_FILE_TYPE = file_type_wg.value


   files_in_input_folder = [f for f in listdir('.') if isfile(f)]
   files_matching_type = [f for f in files_in_input_folder if MY_FILE_TYPE in f]
   filename_wg = Dropdown(options=files_matching_type, description='Input file:')


   accordion = Accordion(children=[file_type_wg, filename_wg])
   accordion.set_title(0, 'File type')
   accordion.set_title(1, 'Select input files')
   accordion
   ```

In my mind, the row '`MY_FILE_TYPE = file_type_wg.value`' can set up a global variable, which can be used in the row '`files_matching_type = [f for f in files_in_input_folder if MY_FILE_TYPE in f]`'. By other words, '`file_type_wg.value`' can be used as an 'input' to create the '`files_matching_type`' list which can be used in the options list of the '`filename_wg`' widget.

In the reality, these widgets are independent of each other. After checking the Jupyter Widgets 7.5.1 documentation, I have the feeling I have to use '`interact`' or '`interaction`' somehow.